# Your message contains invalid characters (bare line feed characters) PHP Mailer

Tags: php, office365, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer to send invoice emails. In some cases I get the undeliverable error of:

***Your message contains invalid characters (bare line feed characters) which the email servers at something.com don't support.***

There are other questions similar to this but none answer/solve my problem.

Like this:
[how to remove bare line feed characters using PHPMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51193204/how-to-remove-bare-line-feed-characters-using-phpmailer) which **does not** have an answer.

After researching for few hour I came to conclusion that I have to replace LF ('\n') to CRLF ('\r\n').

I used the code below to replace any bare line feed characters to normalized line feeds in the email body and make it compliant to servers who does not accept bare line feeds. With the help of [How to replace different newline styles in PHP the smartest way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836632/how-to-replace-different-newline-styles-in-php-the-smartest-way)

```
$body = preg_replace('~(*BSR_ANYCRLF)\R~', "\r\n", $body);
$body = preg_replace("#(?<!\r)\n#si", "\r\n", $body);
$body = preg_replace('~\R~u', "\r\n", $body);
```

**Now**:

after this change. Amount of undeliverable emails reduced, but the problem still exist. (getting undeliverable email couple times a week).

I thought this should work but I don't know how I'm still getting some undeliverable email errors when all the bare line feeds are replaced by the code above.

**Note:** Office 365 used to remove bare line feed characters before. But they changed it for security purposes.

Comment: Are you using PHPMailer 6.x or an older version? Are you sending via SMTP?

Comment: I don't know how to see the version of the PHPMailer

Comment: @Synchro It's either 5.2.X or 5.6.X

Comment: Open the `src/PHPMailer.php` file and it will tell you. If you have a file called `class.phpmailer.php`, you're using a very old version.

Comment: Yes, I have a class.phpmailer.php and the version is shown by public $Version = '5.2.7'; is this it?

Comment: @Synchro The public $LE = "\n"; shall I just change it to public $LE = "\r\n";

Comment: That is a very old version from 2013; it's full of bugs and is vulnerable to several serious attacks. Don't touch the code, just update to the latest version. It always helps to [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki).

Comment: @Synchro Thank you. Is there gonna be any obselete functions or changes I have to make? https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/UPGRADING.md says there are some to change.

Comment: You only need to make changes if you're using the things that are affected. The main thing that changes is how you load the files, which is covered in that doc and the readme.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mailbody = preg_replace("/(\s*[\r\n]+\s*|\s+)/", ' ', $mailbody);
```

By doing so, I was able to solve the issue.